# Data structure for this type of object

Tags: c#, arrays, object, data-structures

I'm new to programming and I had read of types of data structures that exist but I feel like I may pick something that's not optimal for my needs so I need some help from someone who is knowledgeable in the area.

I have 110 objects, each with 14 different objects attatched to them and each of the 14 objects will store an integer.
An example layout would be

```
Object: 1
Objects of the object: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13
Counts of the object objects: 5, 105, 63, etc
```

I need to be able to easily increment the objects of the object if certain criteria is met aka using the '++' and finally I need to be able to print out all values of each object at the end.

I apologize if I've explained poorly. Any suggestions for data structures suitable for this are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the two dimension array like this

```
                int[110,14] myItems = new int[110,14];
                //to increment certain object like ith object with jth object of object
                 myitems[i,j]++;
                 //finally loop like this to print
                for(int i = 0 ; i < 110 ; i++)
                   for(int j = 0 ; j < 14 ; j++
                      Console.WriteLine(myitems[i,j];
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use two dimensional array...
int[,] object_of_objects=new int[object_count][objects_count];

using two nested for loop u can enter values to this....
same way you can access..........

```
for(int rows=0;object_of_objects.getLenght(1);rows++) //get.Lenght(1) will return integer count of number of object of many objects
{
     for(int cols=0;objects_of_objects,getLenght(0);cols++) //get,Lenght(0) will return integer count of objects
     {
          object_of_objects[rows][cols]=set_value_here;
          get_value_here=object_of_objects[rows][cols];
     }
}
```

i Hope this will help